# VueJs Module Not found Axios Post

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Here is my problem, I'm using VueJs and when I'm posting an image to my server, my server modify this image and create another one and returns me the name of the new file, but then occurs the error when I try to require() my new img with the new path... here is my Html :

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div v-if="codeStep == 0">
      <img class="upload_img" :src="filename" />
      <label id="selectfile_button" for="files_selecter" class="btn">Select Image</label>
      <input id="files_selecter" type="file" style="visibility:hidden;" @change="onFileChange"/>
    </div>
    <div v-else="">
      <img class="upload_img" :src="filename" />
      <p> {{ percentCompleted }} </p>
      <button v-on:click="removeImage">{{ cancelText }}</button>
      <button v-if="codeStep == 1" v-on:click="submit">{{ nextText }}</button>
      <button v-else="" v-on:click="finishText">{{ finishText }}</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

There is my filepath declaration :

```
export default {

  data() {
    return {
      codeStep: 0,
      cancelText: "Cancel",
      nextText: "Blur",
      finishText: "Finish",
      filename: require('../../images/default-image.png'),
      attachments: [],
      data: new FormData(),
      errors: {},
      percentCompleted: 0,
    }
  },
```

And there is my posting my function where I get a filename.jpg for example :

```
  submit() {
    this.prepareFields();
    var config = {
      header: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'},
      onUploadProgress: function(progressEvent) {
        this.percentCompleted = Math.round( (progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total );
        this.$forceUpdate();
      }.bind(this)
    };
    let self = this;
    axios.post('/api/upload', this.data, config)
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        console.log('Successful Upload');
        console.log(response.data)
        var res = response.data.filePath;
        console.log(res)

        // The error is here
        self.filename = require('../../images/' + res);
        self.codeStep = 2;
      })
      .catch(function(error){
        console.log(error)
      })
  },
```

And here is the error on my console :

> Error: Cannot find module './goku.jpg'.
>       at webpackContextResolve (.*$:24)
>       at webpackContext (.*$:19)
>       at upload.vue?4b64:134
>       at

I presume it might be that vueJs require doesn't support to call a new file at runtime because it stores everything in dist/ ?

ps: the first default-image.png is well found by vuejs.

Thanks for your time ...

Simon

Comment: i think its cause the require has a relative url. which means that image physically has to be there in your local. from what i understand is that after success, you get name of the image. instead cant you get thr full url of the image and show it? if your server store the images. then you can send the whole image to frontend  and ask user to store in local.

Comment: Yes it's after success, when I try to require the file in its directory I have the module not found error. So you think I should try to send the whole image in binary/stream to the front and then store it instead of sending the image name ? cause I just need to display the new Image on my website.

Comment: yes you have to do that. send the whole image to frontend. other solution is store the binary or base64 format of the converted image in your server database. so whenever user asks the same image, send the stored image binary to front end and show it. and one more thing you dont need to store the binary in front end, if you just want to show. convert the binary as dataurl and attach the dataurl to the image srource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finaly found a way to show up my img whitout using require.
Instead of saving my image in /image, **I store it in /wwwroot/images/ which is a subdirectory from Vuejs webpack RootPath**. Doing this, I can now access to my image directly from the Url for example : *localhost:8080/images/example.jpg*.

```
axios.post('/api/upload', this.data, config)
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        console.log('Successful Upload');
        console.log(response.data)
        var res = response.data.filePath;
        console.log(res)

        // The SOLUTION is here
        self.filename = 'images/' + res;
        self.codeStep = 2;
      })
      .catch(function(error){
        console.log(error)
      })
  },
```